# ArangoDB services restart reason diagnostic

Tags: arangodb

The arangodb services were restarted automatically (because of hang of some process probably) with the following messages in `arangodb.log`:

```
Shutting down services... component=arangodb
Wait for process termination without sending signal coordinator... component=arangodb pid=xxx type=coordinator
Terminated coordinator... component=arangodb pid=xxx type=coordinator
coordinator has terminated component=arangodb pid=xxx type=coordinator
Exited component=arangodb pid=xxx type=coordinator
Wait for process termination without sending signal dbserver... component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
Terminated agent component=arangodb pid=zzz type=agent
agent has terminated component=arangodb pid=zzz type=agent
Exited component=arangodb pid=zzz type=agent
Continue signal termination process dbserver... component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
Terminating dbserver... component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
Wait on yyy returned component=arangodb exit-status=1 trap-cause=-1
Terminated dbserver... component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
dbserver has terminated component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
Exited component=arangodb pid=yyy type=dbserver
```

Is it possible to configure the system to show the reason in some log / trace files?

Comment: Check the system-log/journal, could very well be, that the decision was made by the system/OS not arangodb itselt (OOM killer comes to mind).

Comment: /var/log/messages entries are not available (the log was rotated), but according to the messages above (Shutting down services, Wait for process termination, etc) it doesn't look like OOM killer came into the game. It would be nothing to shutdown in this case. It looks like the controlled shutdown / restart process...